# Tensorflow: opt.compute_gradients() returns values different from the weight difference of opt.apply_gradients()

Tags: tensorflow

**Question:** What is the most efficient way to get the delta of my weights in the most efficient way in a TensorFlow network?

**Background**: I've got the operators hooked up as follows (thanks to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687761/efficiently-grab-gradients-from-tensorflow)):

```
self.cost = `the rest of the network`
self.rmsprop = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(lr,rms_decay,0.0,rms_eps)
self.comp_grads = self.rmsprop.compute_gradients(self.cost)
self.grad_placeholder = [(tf.placeholder("float", shape=grad[1].get_shape(), name="grad_placeholder"), grad[1]) for grad in self.comp_grads]
self.apply_grads = self.rmsprop.apply_gradients(self.grad_placeholder)
```

Now, to feed in information, I run the following:

```
feed_dict = `training variables`
grad_vals = self.sess.run([grad[0] for grad in self.comp_grads], feed_dict=feed_dict)

feed_dict2 = `feed_dict plus gradient values added to self.grad_placeholder`
self.sess.run(self.apply_grads, feed_dict=feed_dict2)
```

The command of `run(self.apply_grads)` will update the network weights, but when I compute the differences in the starting and ending weights (`run(self.w1)`), those numbers are different than what is stored in `grad_vals[0]`.  I figure this is because the RMSPropOptimizer does more to the raw gradients, but I'm not sure what, or where to find out what it does.

So back to the question:  How do I get the delta on my weights in the most efficient way?  Am I stuck running `self.w1.eval(sess)` multiple times to get the weights and calc the difference?  Is there something that I'm missing with the `tf.RMSPropOptimizer` function.

Thanks!

Comment: Source code links: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dc237a98ab7c28ca5d307fe523a6caf2bc6a4810/tensorflow/python/training/training_ops.py#L114 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/16d395e5dea687ab3aece0a462e631de25c8d77d/tensorflow/python/training/rmsprop.py

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc#L143 is were the ApplyRMSProp happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RMSprop does not subtract the gradient from the parameters but use more complicated formula involving a combination of:

- a momentum, if the corresponding parameter is not 0
- a gradient step, rescaled non uniformly (on each coordinate) by the square root of the squared average of the gradient.

For more information you can refer to [these slides](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec6.pdf) or [this recent paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.04390v1.pdf).

The delta is first computed in memory by tensorflow in the slot variable 'momentum' and then the variable is updated (see [the C++ operator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc#L134)).
Thus, you should be able to access it and construct a delta node with `delta_w1 = self.rmsprop.get_slot(self.w1, 'momentum')`. (I have not tried it yet.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the weights to the list of things to fetch each run call. Then you can compute the deltas outside of TensorFlow since you will have the iterates. This should be reasonably efficient, although it might incur an extra elementwise difference, but to avoid that you might have to hack around in the guts of the optimizer and find where it puts the update before it applies it and fetch that each step. Fetching the weights each call shouldn't do wasteful extra evaluations of part of the graph at least.

RMSProp does complicated scaling of the learning rate for each weight. Basically it divides the learning rate for a weight by a running average of the magnitudes of recent gradients of that weight.