# optimizer.applyGradient doesnt work in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, tensorflow, gradient

I am trying to change gradients in tensorflow and after that trying to update with applyGradient() function. This is my code and it doesnt work

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE)
        for j in range(n_rounds):
            sample = np.random.randint(row, size=int(batch_size))
            batch_xs = temp[sample][:]
            batch_ys = output[sample][:]
            vars_with_grads = sess.run(optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy), feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
            noiseAddedGradient = []
            print(vars_with_grads)
            for var in vars_with_grads:
                gaussianNoise = [np.random.normal(MEAN_FOR_AUTOENCODER, SCALE_FOR_AUTOENCODER, var[0].shape) for i in range(int(batch_size))]
                totalGaussianNoise = [sum(x) for x in zip(*gaussianNoise)]
                averageGaussianNoise = [x1 / float(batch_size) for x1 in totalGaussianNoise]
                averageGaussianNoiseList = np.array(averageGaussianNoise).flatten().reshape(var[0].shape)
                noiseAddedGradient.append((tf.Variable(np.add(var[0], averageGaussianNoiseList), dtype=np.float32), var[1]))
            appliedGradient = sess.run(optimizer.apply_gradients(noiseAddedGradient))
```

it returns error function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Downloads/objectPerturbation.py", line 214, in <module>
    appliedGradient = sess.run(optimizer.apply_gradients(noiseAddedGradient))
  File "/home/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 384, in apply_gradients
    p = _get_processor(v)
  File "/home/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 98, in _get_processor
    if v.op.type == "ReadVariableOp":
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'op'
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: You are adding operations to the graph in your training loop. You don't want to do that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230559/processing-time-gets-longer-and-longer-after-each-iteration-tensorflow for the reason.

Comment: Can you please explain why? I just want to add noise to gradients. It may be slower but it is not important for me now.

Comment: It's not about what you do, it's about how you do it. TF is made to set up the graph first, and then run the graph in a loop without changing the graph. You should not have calls to tf.Variable or optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy) or optimizer.apply_gradients(noiseAddedGradient) in your loop as they add something to the computation graph in every single iteration. Instead, you want to *create them outside your training loop* and just *run them* in the training loop. Instead of creating a variable for every python value, use feed dicts to feed python values into TF.

Comment: Actually if you are doing something in a distributed setting and have to send the gradients to other machines then having it in the graph is not suitable.  It can also be done the way proposed for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try chaging it like this.  The gradients should be computed in the graph.

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE)
grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)
grad_placeholder = [(tf.placeholder("float", shape=grad[1].get_shape()), grad[1] for grad in grads]
apply_placeholder_op = opt.apply_gradients(grad_placeholder)

#added in case you don't do this
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for j in range(n_rounds):
        sample = np.random.randint(row, size=int(batch_size))
        batch_xs = temp[sample][:]
        batch_ys = output[sample][:]
        vars_with_grads = sess.run(grads, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
        #Add gaussian noise to gradients
        feed_dict = {}
        for i in range(len(grad_placeholder)):
            feed_dict[grad_placeholder[i][0]] = add_gaussian_noise_fn(grad_vals[i])
        sess.run(apply_placeholder_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)

#separate function to make it more general to do whatever you want with grads
def add_gaussian_noise_fn(x):
  return x + np.random.normal(size=x.shape)
```

Idea is similar to this previous post:
[Efficiently grab gradients from TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687761/efficiently-grab-gradients-from-tensorflow)

Comment: same error as before? you can also try sess.run(grads[0])

Comment: yes same error as before. I just want to add noise but i cant do it.

Comment: I think I misread the error initially.  I'll try to update my answer with a different version.  The main issue now is that your creating a tf.Variable outside of the computation graph.  You should do just pure numpy afterwards and then add it back to the graph.

Comment: Let me know if you still have any issues with the updated answer.